# Test for both: boolean and string?

Tags: bash

I'd like to cheick that the one of two options are set: either the `bin` to `true`, or `str` is provided:

```
bin=false; str=; if $bin -o [ -n "$str" ]; then echo yes; fi
```

doesn't `echo`es anything, as it should be, but:

```
bin=false; str='str'; if $bin -o [ -n "$str" ]; then echo yes; fi
```

doesn't echo either - while it should. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `-o` option is getting passed to `false`. You need `||`:

```
bin=false; str=; if $bin || [ -n "$str" ]; then echo yes; fi
bin=false; str='str'; if $bin || [ -n "$str" ]; then echo yes; fi
```

Comment: @Adobe: The reason that `-o` isn't working is that it's not part of `if` syntax (it's not getting passed to `false`, but *with* `false` to `if`), but it's part of the syntax of `test` (aka `[`).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Set `$bin` to `echo`. You will see that `-o` is getting passed to `$bin`, whose result goes to `if`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I overlooked the fact that `if` executes its argument. However, the part I said about `test` is correct.